# Firebase photo uploaded to imageview would disappear after a user re log-in

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

the image i would upload in my user profile would be stored to the firebase database child.

[image]

How to set the imageview into the one you uploaded?

My problem is I want to show this information when that specific user Log in to their account, Because so far I'm only on the uploading part where the user can upload the photo and then the photo uploaded would be displayed. But after logging in again. The photo uploaded would disappear.

**Code**

```
private void chooseImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String useruid = user.getUid();
    final DatabaseReference img = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Accounts").child("Users").child(useruid);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        StorageReference filepath = storageReference.child("Images").child(filePath.getLastPathSegment());
        filepath.putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                String downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                img.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl);
                imageView.setImageURI(filePath);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: the above code is when you go to the gallery then add the image in the imageview that you got from the gallery. On a Login activity, you need to retrieve the user information... so you need to retrieve image also.. (as you posted it is in your database)

Comment: Hmmmm Do I do it like this? http://prntscr.com/ijfi6w

Comment: in the activity, where you retrieve the info of the user after he logins he, just also retrieve the image..`String url = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();` and use Glide library to show the image in the imageview https://bumptech.github.io/glide/

Comment: Thank you now It's working :D